# Softmax on the variable length sequence in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have samples which have 2D shape `(say [a, 10])`. Where a changes from sample to sample. I am doing a training with `batch size = 1` to avoid the problem of variable batch size. I created the following `LSTM` network. Now the problem is that my target is a probability vector of shape `[1,a,1]`. The sum of the probability vector is 1 for each sample.

I want to apply a `softmax` activation on the final layer so that I can compare it with the target. What should I do?

```python
    Layer (type)                            Output Shape                        Param #       
==========================================================================================
lstm_21 (LSTM)                          (1, None, 32)                       7808          
__________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_22 (LSTM)                          (1, None, 8)                        1312          
__________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (TimeDistributed)    (1, None, 1)                        9             
==========================================================================================
```

Here is my code

```python
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(1, None, len(features))))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')))

print(model.summary(90))

model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error',
              optimizer = 'adam')


def generate_arrays_from_pd(df, arr_df):
    while True:
        for i in range(arr_df.shape[0]):
            a1 = arr_df[i, 0]
            a2 = arr_df[i, 1]
            batch_x = df.loc[a1:a2, features].as_matrix().reshape((1, -1, len(features)))
            batch_y = df.loc[a1:a2, "mkt_shr"].as_matrix().reshape((1, -1, 1))
            yield(batch_x, batch_y)

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_pd(dat_train, arr_train), steps_per_epoch=arr_train.shape[0], epochs = 10, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Add a Global max pooling layer and then a dense layer with a softmax activation

Comment: Are your targets a true probability distribution or some one hot class labels? Basically what are you trying to predict?

Comment: They are true probability distribution (which sum upto 1)

Comment: For example (0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2) is target of one sample

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Global max pooling layer and then a dense layer with a softmax activation.

The global max pooling layer takes the max vector over the steps dimension so there will be no more different shape of data and then you can apply a dense layer ith the softmax activation.

Comment: Global max pooling will take max over all dimensions. Basically converting [1,5, 10] sample to [1,10] and then adding a dense layer with softmax activation will convert it to a [1,1] prediction. However, the prediction should be a [1,5,10] size array. Since that is my target.